# How to match between 2 list which is approximate word

Tags: python

I have parent list below

parent_list = `['AWS', 'GCP', 'ALIBABA', 'AZURE']`

The incoming input is sentence = `The use is asking for AWS and GCP`

I need to check the incoming input with parent_list and put in the list

Expected out is `[AWS , GCP]`

My code is below which is working fine

`[i for i in parent_list if i in sentence ]`

Now I need to do some approximate match let's say if sentence = `The use is asking for AliBab and gcp`

You can see that `AliBab` is approximate to `ALIBABA`

Expected out is `['ALIBABA', 'GCP']`

Comment: use Levenshtein Distance - see https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the definition of approximation match.

If `substring` is a criteria then you can iterate over the words of the sentence and parent list and return matches if the word of the sentence appear as a substring of the element of the parent list.

```
matches = [elt for elt in parent_list if any(word.lower() in elt.lower() for word in sentence.split())]
```

---

You can use `re.split()` to split on multiple delimiters:

```
parent_list = ['AWS', 'GCP', 'ALIBABA', 'AZURE']
sentence = "The use is asking for AliBab and gcp"
import re
matches = [elt for elt in parent_list if any(word.lower() in elt.lower() or elt.lower() in word.lower() for word in re.split('[, ]', sentence))]
print(matches)

sentence = "The use is asking for AWS,GCP"
matches = [elt for elt in parent_list if any(word.lower() in elt.lower() or elt.lower() in word.lower() for word in re.split('[, ]', sentence))]
print(matches)
```

Comment: if my input is "The use is asking for AWS,GCP" how to get the output ['AWS', 'GCP']

Comment: you can use `re.split()` in that case to split on multiple delimiters, please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try might be this:

```
types = ['AWS', 'GCP', 'ALIBABA', 'AZURE']
sentence = 'The use is asking for AW and GCP or something'

result = []
for word in sentence.split():
    for t in types:
        if word.lower() in t.lower() or t.lower() in word.lower():
            result.append(t)

print(result)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
result = [t for word in sentence.split()
           for t in types
           if word.lower() in t.lower() or t.lower() in word.lower()]
```

it looks cleaner, but bit complicated

for more than 1 delimeter, use:

```
import re
for word in re.split(' |,', sentence):
```

like:

```
result = [t for word in re.split(' |,', sentence)
           for t in types
           if word.lower() in t.lower() or t.lower() in word.lower()]
```

about adding delimiter, ',' is different one from ', '

Comment: one quick question if my input is "The use is asking for AWS,GCP" how to get the output ['AWS', 'GCP']

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
parent_list = ['AWS', 'GCP', 'ALIBABA', 'AZURE']
used_words = []
string = "The use is asking for AWS and GCP"
for word in parent_list:
    if(word.lower() in string.lower()):
        used_words.append(word)

print(used_words)
```

Comment: if my input is "The use is asking for AWS,GCP" how to get the output ['AWS', 'GCP']